# Ruby on Rails: How do you add add zeros in front of a number if it's under 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to convert single digit numbers to two-digit numbers like so:

```
9 ==> 09
5 ==> 05
12 == 12
4 ==> 04
```

I figure I could put a bunch of if-else statements (if number is under 10, then do a gsub) but figure that's horrible coding. I know Rails has number_with_precision but I see that it only applies to decimal numbers. Any ideas on how to convert single-digits to two-digits?

Comment: More generalized variant of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32139291/12484

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Did you mean `sprintf '%02d', n`?

```
irb(main):003:0> sprintf '%02d', 1
=> "01"
irb(main):004:0> sprintf '%02d', 10
=> "10"
```

You might want to reference the [format table for `sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962) in the future, but for this particular example `'%02d'` means to print an integer (`d`) taking up at least 2 characters (`2`) and left-padding with zeros instead of spaces (`0`).

Comment: You should probably use `%02i` for this case as it is more obvious that the output is and is supposed to be an integer, d is less intuitive for people who are not as accustomed to using `sprintf`.

Comment: you can simply `'%02d'%1` without sprintf

Answer (score 215):

A lot of people using `sprintf` (which is the right thing to do), and I think if you want to do this **for a string** it's best to keep in mind the `rjust` and `ljust` methods:

```
"4".rjust(2, '0')
```

This will make the `"4"` right justified by ensuring it's at least `2` characters long and pad it with `'0'`. `ljust` does the opposite.

Comment: This is only better than sprintf if you want to allow strings. Otherwise I'd use sprintf, since it throws an exception (like it should) if I accidentally use a string.

Comment: If you know you're starting with a string representation of a number, I like this better than sprintf for performance. Using `rjust` avoids the cost of parsing sprintf's format string, converting a string to a number, and converting that number back to a string. Plus, it's (arguably) easy for a human to understand what the code is trying to do at a glance.

Answer (score 35):

how about `"%02d" % 9`? see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25 and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf .

Answer (score 12):

Try this, it should work:

```rb
abc = 5
puts "%.2i" % abc # => 05

abc = 5.0
puts "%.2f" % abc # => 5.00
```

Comment: Awesome, Exactly what I was looking for. Is there any documentation available or how have you come to learn about it ?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25

more info: https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 2):

[Rubocop](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FormatString) recommends `format` over `sprintf` and `%`. I think it's more intuitive:

```
format('%02d', 7) # => "07"
format('%02d', 12) # => "12"
```