# Padding a number with zeros

Tags: ruby, string

How do I represent a number `user.id` as a string with:

- `00` padded to the left if `user.id` is in range 0 to 9

  `# => "00#{user.id}"`
- `0` padded if `user.id` is in range 10 to 99

  `# => "0#{user.id}"`
- nothing padded otherwise

  `# => "#{user.id}"`

For example, having `user.id = 1`, it would produce `"001"`, having `user.id = 11`, it would produce `"011"`, and having `user.id = 111`, it would produce `"111"`.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
puts 1.to_s.rjust(3, "0")
#=> 001
puts 10.to_s.rjust(3, "0")
#=> 010
puts 100.to_s.rjust(3, "0")
#=> 100
```

The above code would convert your user.id into a string, then String.rjust() method would consider its length and prefix appropriate number of zeros.

Comment: I think @sawa has a good anwser too, but it's less Ruby-ish and more like what I see when working in Python. Both work though.

Comment: @wurde If you call this `String#%` as formatting method, it will be readable :) We call _format_ string.

Answer (score 43):

You better use string format.

```
"%03d" % 1    #=> "001"
"%03d" % 10   #=> "010"
"%03d" % 100  #=> "100"
"%03d" % user.id # => what you want
```

Comment: in array `%W[#{'%03d' % 1} #{'%03d' % 100}] => ["001", "100"]`

Comment: For this purpose I use always `String#%`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I will use `rjust`, but upvote for quick response!

Answer (score 5):

[`String#rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
user.id
#⇒ 5
user.id.to_s.rjust(3, '0')
#⇒ "005"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the string `"'%03d' % #{user.id}"`

Comment: @Зелёный run both in console and check the out put .

Answer (score 3):

`Kernel#format`, or `Kernel#sprintf` can also be used:

```rb
format('%03d', user.id)

# or

sprintf('%03d', user.id)
```

As a side note, `Kernel#format` or `Kernel#sprintf` are recommended over `String#%` due to the ambiguity of the `%` operator (for example seeing `a % b` in the code doesn't make it clear if this is integer modulo, or string format). Also `%` takes as arguments an array, which might involve allocating a new object, which might carry a (maybe insignificant, but present) performance penalty.